# In Google Apps Script how do I check if a reference is out of range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have some Google Apps Script code which works with Google Sheets. In one segment of code there are some instances where it throws an exception.

Here is the exception:

```
Exception: Cell reference out of range
```

Here is the line of code (and the one preceding it) that is throwing the exception:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reservations');
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell(); // This is where the exception is thrown
```

This error happens but not consistently. What I want to do is check if sheet.getActiveCell() is pointing to a reference out of range or if it is returning a valid value. If it is pointing to a reference that is out of range I would like to set the value of cell to an alternative value.

How do I check if sheet.getActiveCell() is returning a value that is in range?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please add a brief description of your search/reserarch efforts as is suggesed in [ask].

Comment: Related [Google sheets cell reference out of range on getActiveCell()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36305436/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use [getCurrentCell](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCurrentCell()), then instead of throwing an exception, it returns null if there is no active cell. [There are some difference between the getCurrentCell and getActiveCell though](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61905950/1595451).

With getCurrentCell, you can do this:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reservations');
 var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
 if(cell) {
   // Rest of your code that needs access to the active cell
 } else {
   // There is no active cell, do something else
 }
```

If you can't use getCurrentCell, then you can use a try-catch block to catch the exception.

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Reservations');
 try {
   var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
   // Rest of your code that needs access to the active cell
 } catch (e) {
   // There is no active cell, do something else
 }
```

Comment: Related [What's the difference between getActiveCell and getCurrentCell in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61905950/1595451)